# Cannot reinstall Windows 10 Store

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, windows-store

My Windows Store has gone missing since the last update. I found [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt185364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to reinstall it but when I run the script I get this error:

```
Add-AppxPackage: Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.255.4.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\USERS\[USERNAME]\desktop\reinstall-preinstalledApps.ps1:35 char:2
 +     Add-AppxPackage -register $PackagePath -DisableDevelopmentMode
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          :ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...dleManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId: PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Apparently, the update no longer uses that folder because in its place there is a folder called 'Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe'. However, that folder does not contain a file called AppxBundleManifest.xml and the only thing in the AppxMetadata folder is a file called CodeIntegrity.cat

I then found [this page](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/how-reinstall-windows-10-store) and ran the command like this:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

This resulted in some sort of merge error:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered. Merge Failure : error 0x80070003 : Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package because there was a merge failure with the following file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\resources.pri NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 5e87878d-3da6-0000-9f00-895ea63dd101 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 5e87878d-3da6-0000-9f00-895ea63dd101 At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Win ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

The command Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 5e87878d-3da6-0000-9f00-895ea63dd101 gives this:

```
Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    301          The calling process is powershell.exe
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    603          Started deployment Register operation on a package with main parameter: AppxManifest.xml and Options: 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing
                                       app deployment issues.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\a0173705-8c56-45bb-a57f-3ec254fc1508_S-1-5-21-881075586-1145924869-2759436506-1000_1.rslc for Register
                                       Operation on Package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    607          Deployment Register operation on package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe has been de-queued and is running for user LIONGATE1\Robert B. Miller.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    613          Adding uri to the list of Uris: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    561          Not staging roaming data for package Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe. The application state is already present.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    10000        About to service package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting the package state to disabled returned with 0x0.
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    827          Capability parsing started for the package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
12/24/2015 10:46:45 AM    5502         Merge Failure : error 0x80070003 : Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package because there was a merge failure with the following file:
                                       C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\resources.pri
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    303          error 0x80070003: While preparing to process the request, the system failed to register the windows.MRT extension due to the following error: The system cannot find the path
                                       specified.
                                       .
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    300          error 0x80070003: Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe package due to the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.
                                       .
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    605          The last successful state reached was ResolvedDeferredRegistrations. Failure occurred before reaching the next state RegistrationChanged.
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    10001        Finished servicing package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting the package state to enabled returned with 0x0.
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    401          Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppxManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80073CF6.
                                       See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
12/24/2015 10:46:46 AM    404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with error 0x80073CF6. The specific error text for this failure is: Merge
                                       Failure : error 0x80070003 : Cannot register the Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe package because there was a merge failure with the following file:
                                       C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\resources.pri
```

I checked and the folder C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.5.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe\ does not exist.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: The first script is broken (missing ``\``) - `C:Program Files\...` should be `C:\Program Files\...`

Comment: @DavidPostill That was a typo -- I retyped all that into this forum. The original command contained the backslash.

Comment: the version 1511 doesn't like those powershell commands and breaks apps. Use "refresh" to get them back. But this removes all desktop programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I reran the version 1511 "November Update" from DVD using the option to preserve files and applications. This repaired the problem with Windows Store.